# Updating a Flask extension and maintaining state

Tags: python, flask

I am finding that maintaining changes [of object variables] to a flask extension is very frustrating. Surely there exists multiple use cases where updating an extensions properties are required to endure beyond a single request? Moreover, even if the framework wishes to force statelessness upon the developer, it seems ridiculous to prevent any override mechanism.

To give context, I've adapted the redis flask extension for redis-py-cluster. Upon initialization of the flask app, the extension is initialized. At a later stage if the cluster nodes are updated, re-connection works fine, but does not persist across the api calls. In other words, the original object state at app initialization time is used on each request in stead of the updated state. Yes, the object is the same object (simple ID checking proves this), but the object members' state is always reset.

Which redis cluster nodes are used has nothing to do at all with maintaining statelessness across api calls. It has zero impact on the api calls themselves, hence i ask, why must my object/extension be bound to this almost reincarnation-like behaviour of state?

And more importantly, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can you please show us how you are updating your state? Flask doesn't put any restrictions on how you maintain state in your extension. Also, does your extension handle multiple processes running in the WSGI server? In that case the WSGI server will spin up multiple processes, and these *do not share state* purely because the Python processes don't share state by default.